# How to Reset Branch to Base of Another Branch Without Deleting the Branch

Tags: git, github

Assuming I checkout to a new branch `b2` from branch `b1`. How can I reset `b2` to `master` branch instead of deleting branch `b2`, checking out branch `master`, then checking out to new branch `b2`.

Basically, this is what I do :

```
git checkout b1

git checkout -b b2

git checkout master

git branch -D b2 

git checkout -b b2
```

Is there a better option ?

Comment: You can use `git checkout -B` (uppercase `B`) for this too. It's a relatively rare thing to want, so be careful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) b2 to the same commit hash as master.

```
# find the commit hash you want with 
git log

# reset the branch to that commit 
git reset --hard <commit hash you wanted>
```

Is this better than your proposed solution? I don't think so, but it is an alternative.

WARNING: Make sure you do not have commits on the branch you're resetting that you need for work.